# C# Client Server learning

Tags: c#

I would like to know where I can go and learn more about client server C#, XMAL, and MS SQL server programming. I am doing a lot of ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, and even a lot of PHP/MYSQL MVC with Joomla and Wordpress but I want to learn more about client server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below the list of tutorial links , for the technologies you have mentioned

1. [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc)
2. [Generic C# , technology Hands On , SQL , Client Server computing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/cc138021.aspx)
3. [Silver Light](http://silverlight.net)
4. [SQL SERVER](http://www.functionx.com/sqlserver)
5. [WPF](http://wpf.codeplex.com)

Hope this helps ,

Thanks,
Vijay